# WebGL context lost error on Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

While loading a product into the Forge viewer using latest version of Chrome, user receives a message that states "WebGL context lost".   They had a model loaded into the viewer which was working fine, clicked on another model to view it and that is when they received the error message (see attachment).

Is there anything that can be done to mitigate or resolve this issue?

[Click for Picture of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K3WC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities for this issue:

- The graphic card driver is out-date, please try to upgrade it: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/bim-360/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Error-WebGL-context-lost-when-viewing-files-in-BIM-360.html
- There might be some viewer instances that haven't been destroyed properly. you can type `NOP_VIEWERS` in your browser console to see if the array length is greater than two. To fix this, you can take advantage of `viewer.finish()` before loading other models.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful!

Comment: In my situation, I need to keep multiple DOM elements each carrying a viewer instance. After loading a few, older viewers getting this error (which is understood). Is there a Viewer function I can call to programmatically check if this condition has occurred? Or, an event that I can catch?